# Is it "Gratulon!" or "Gratulojn!"?

Tags: word-choice

I've seen both. It seems to be random. What's the explanation? Does it matter which one I say? Same with ***multan dankon*** and ***multajn dankojn***.

Comment: I would say that it's the difference of being thankful for one thing versus multiple things, but that's just a hunch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both *Gratulon* and *Gratulojn* exist and are used in the same way.

*Multan dankon* and *multajn dankojn* also exist both but sure *multan dankon* is used much more often.

Comment: I would just like to add that I think that _gratulon_ is common because it fits in with _saluton_, _dankon_, _bonan tagon_, etc. And _gratulojn_ s probably common because in many big languages "congratulation**s**" is a plural word. In English, but also in most (or all?) Romance languages, such as Spanish (felicitacion**es**), Portuguese (parabén**s**), French (félicitation**s**), Italian (congratulazion**i**), Catalan (felicitat**s**), etc. Which one people use probably depends a lot on their language background and their personal preference.

Comment: Very interesting observation, Raizin! And you can add the Romanian plural Felicitări! to your list!

Answer (score 5):

I think this is simply a case where Esperanto is as logical or illogical as natural languages.
We say "thank you", "many thanks" in English as well and I don't know of a definite rule to guide the usage. Compare this to "tack" and "tack så mycket" in Swedish and "merci" and "merci beaucoup" in French.
There clearly is a need to intensify and/or pluralize thanks as well as congratulations in any language.

"*gratulon*" shows 22 hits in Tekstaro, among them this from *Paroladoj de Zamenhof*.

> *en la nomo de la tuta esperantistaro nian koran gratulon, nian dankon
>   por lia granda laboro*

"*gratulojn*" has 28 hits, among them this quote from *Vivo vokas*:

> *Miajn korajn gratulojn pro la naskiĝotago!*